# Is there a way to save a pre-compiled AutoTokenizer?

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers

Sometimes, we'll have to do something like this to extend a pre-trained tokenizer:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

from datasets import load_dataset


ds_de = load_dataset("mc4", 'de')
ds_fr = load_dataset("mc4", 'fr')

de_tokenizer = tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(
    ds_de['text'],vocab_size=50_000
)

fr_tokenizer = tokenizer.train_new_from_iterator(
    ds_fr['text'],vocab_size=50_000
)

new_tokens_de = set(de_tokenizer.vocab).difference(tokenizer.vocab)
new_tokens_fr = set(fr_tokenizer.vocab).difference(tokenizer.vocab)
new_tokens = set(new_tokens_de).union(new_tokens_fr)


tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
    'moussaKam/frugalscore_tiny_bert-base_bert-score'
)

tokenizer.add_tokens(list(new_tokens))

tokenizer.save_pretrained('frugalscore_tiny_bert-de-fr')
```

And then when loading the tokenizer,

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
  'frugalscore_tiny_bert-de-fr', local_files_only=True
)
```

It takes pretty long to load from `%%time` in a Jupyter cell:

```
CPU times: user 34min 20s
Wall time: 34min 22s
```

I guess this is due to regex compilation for the added tokens which was also raised in https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/914

I think it's okay since it'll load once and the work can be done without redoing the regex compiles.

#### But, is there a way to just save the tokenizer in binary form and avoid the whole regex compilation the next time?

Comment: can't you simply use pickle?

Comment: Interesting approach to extending the tokenizer with new tokens specific to your datasets. Regarding the loading time, you're correct in assuming the regex compilation contributes significantly to it. As of my current knowledge, directly saving the tokenizer in a binary format that bypasses regex compilation upon loading isn't supported out of the box by the HuggingFace's Transformers library. However, this would be a valuable feature to suggest to their development team or explore if there are alternative serialization methods that could expedite the loading process.

Comment: Hi there. I have exactly same problem with you. Do you find the solution? If you have, can you share it please?

Answer (score 1):

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Instantiate the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Save the tokenizer to a directory in binary format
tokenizer.save_pretrained("/path/to/save_directory", save_tokenizer=True)

# Load the tokenizer from the saved directory without recompiling the regex
loaded_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("/path/to/save_directory")
```

Comment: Wouldn't the same loading of the regexes repeat when loading the tokenizer?

Comment: import pickle
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Instantiate the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Serialize and save the tokenizer using pickle
with open("/path/to/tokenizer.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, f)

# Load the tokenizer from the saved file
with open("/path/to/tokenizer.pkl", "rb") as f:
    loaded_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

Merge the vocabs inside sentencepiece and use `Tokenizer` instead `TokenizerFast`. `TokenizerFast` uses `tokenizer.json` instead `sentencepiece.bpe.model`. You add extra vocab inside sentencepiece model of `Tokenizer` and once you get the merged tokenizer, you can also load it from `TokenizerFast`.

Here's the reference code for merging vocab: https://github.com/ymcui/Chinese-LLaMA-Alpaca/blob/main/scripts/merge_tokenizer/merge_tokenizers.py

Answer (score 0):

you're correct this the right code:

```
import pickle
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Instantiate the tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

# Serialize and save the tokenizer using pickle
with open("/path/to/tokenizer.pkl", "wb") as f:
pickle.dump(tokenizer, f)

# Load the tokenizer from the saved file
with open("/path/to/tokenizer.pkl", "rb") as f:
loaded_tokenizer = pickle.load(f)
```